# Generating a list of uncreated foreign keys

Tags: python, django

How I can get the items that are **NOT** translated in a given language when my models are structured as follow:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    id = ...

class Translation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.ForeignKey('languages.Language')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

I need an efficient solution are there will be million of records.

So I basically need to loop over a list and add the missing translations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a really efficient way. At least not with information you have provided. I would do it this way.

```
from itertools import product

existing_translatinos = {'_'.join((t.item_id + t.language_id)) for t in Translation.objects.all()}

for i, l in product(Item.objects.all(), Language.objects.all()):
    if '_'.join((i.id, l.id)) not in existing_translations: 
        Translation.objects.create(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How I can get the items that are **NOT** translated in a given language

```
items = Items.objects.filter(translation__language=lang_obj)
```

Above query will give you all the items which doesn't have a translation in a particular language `lang_obj`. Now, you can loop over these items and add the missing translations.

Comment: That would takes ages for million of records.

Comment: Why would you think so? It will give you all the items which haven't been translated to a particular language in single query.